# Is there a community of TSQLUnit users somewhere?

Tags: sql-server-2005, testing

I am relatively new to using SQL Server (we're on 2005) but not to database design, creation, and programming.  I have decided to use TSQLUnit for the testing we want to do, and have been learning it as I go.  But, there are some things that have not become clear over time, and it gets pretty frustrating to want to do a particular type of test and not be able to do it.  I'm not sure if the problem is with SQL Server (very unlikely), TSQLUnit (unlikely) or me (very likely).

Does anyone know of an online resource or community of TSQLUnit users that I could consult?  I would like to both contribute when I can and gain benefit when needed.

Any suggestions or links will be appreciated.

Comment: try www.sqlservercentral.com

Answer (score 0):

There are so many

## SQLBangalore on Facebook.

Even you can post questions in SQlcetral as well.